# xdsoft taking this date 01 Jan 1970 1:00 AM not taking current date?

Tags: php, datepicker

This is my HTML and jQuery code. It's not taking the selected date, it only takes 01 Jan 1970 1:00 AM this format in XDSoft date picker.

```
<input type="text"  name="date-input"  class="datepicker add-order span2" value="01-01-2016" id="datetimepicker">
<input type="text"  name="time-input"  class="datepicker add-order span2" value="10:10:00" id="datetimepicker_start_time">

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd-m-Y',
    formatDate: 'Y-m-d',
    timepicker: false,
    value:'01-01-2016'
});

$('#datetimepicker_start_time').datetimepicker({
    startDate: '+1971/05/01', //or 1986/12/08
    datepicker: false,
    format: 'h:i',
    step: 30,
    value:'10:10:00'
});
```

Comment: @Sam Onela Its a  xdsoft  plugin from [this] (http://xdsoft.net/) website not a bootstrap plugin

Comment: should the *startDate* option be set on the date picker (i.e. `$('#datetimepicker')`) instead of the (start) time picker (i.e. `$('#datetimepicker_start_time')`)? I see [that option in the documentation](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#starDate) but the [example](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#startdateex) doesn't appear to work as it seems it should. Did you purchase a license? If so you could request support, or [add an issue on the repo](https://github.com/xdan/periodpicker/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=startDate).

Comment: @SamOnela its free plug in, and i solved that issue, thank you sir

Comment: Okay - for posterity, would you mind either updating your question with your solution or [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: @SamOnela  Sir, I solved that with help of PHP, I noticed that date is printing, but while passing date value to database it need to replace some special characters, so that point I used preg_replace here is example                             ` $date1 = str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('date-input') . " " . $this->input->post('time-input'));
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($date1));`

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php  
   $date1 = str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('date-input') . " " . $this->input->post('time-input'));
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($date1));
 ?>
```

Comment: Is `$date` used to set the value attribute of the input elements and/or the JavaScript parameters, or is it used for something else (e.g. Setting a value in a database, etc.)?

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @samOnela   `$date` used to Setting a value in a database